# Cant display images on website Webpack React-dom unexpected syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom

error message:

```
 webpack-dev-server

/home/panecitodigital/Desktop/react-course-projects/cse-app/webpack.config.js:35
  };
   ^
```

my webpack.config.js

It was working fine until i tried to add the file-loader to work with images, every time i try to fix the mistake the cmd tells me i have a new one comes up. A newbie that has tried the solutions that were on the web with no results too. Please help :) will pay foward when im not a newb

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test:    /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader',
      ]
    },
    {
      test : /\.jpg$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader : 'file-loader'
    }],
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
  };
```

Comment: It looks like you have your `devtool` and `devServer` inside of `module`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Tholle No. It is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules:[
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }, {
        test:    /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader',
        ]
        },
        {
        test : /\.jpg$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader : 'file-loader'
        }
    ]
  }


};
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an `}` after your rules in module. The error is showing up on the last line because it's not expecting the `;` it's expecting one more `}` to close the entire object.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test:    /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test : /\.jpg$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader : 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },   // <---- this is missing
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe looking for validators too would help, it was really funny that when the path variable was declared on the first line of code the cmd wrote that it had been defined twice on the line after the last one for some reason, but skipping the first line solved the last issue, look foward to adding images to website